# WSO2 Community Edition - Entitlement extension

Tags: wso2

I am using WSO2 Community Edition : 
[image]

I was trying to add the entitlement extension according to this URL :
https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/97563684

So I clone the GIT repo from here, and do the maven package :
https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-agent-entitlement-proxy

But failed with following error :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-18 12:20:17,190] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.ui.AddExtensionProcessor} - File uploading failed. Content is not set properly.
```

TID: [-1] [] [2020-06-18 12:20:17,272] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve} - Could not handle request: null java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.Utils.getTenantDomain(Utils.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.initCarbonContext(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help or suggestion to fix this is appreciated. 
Last but not least, I am new to WSO2 extension coding, anyone can provide a helloworld extension is also appreciated.

Comment: Hi @SK999, the repository related to the entitlement-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar found in https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/97563684 is available in https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim/tree/master/XACML-handler. I think you should try building this repo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I mixed up API Manager with Identity Server.[image]

The function Entitlement > PAP > Policy Administration is inside Identity Server without any build / configuration required :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 products does not have "Community Edition" vs "any other commercial edition". All products are fully open source.

Better option is to download the respective product itself, rather than building by yourself.

Also you can build the products yourself. It is easy to build the top level product like "product-apim", "product-is", "product-ei". Then build the relevant connectors and add it to respective product.

The "Carbon" mentioned in the image, is the core, component framework which most of the WSO2 products are built upon. You can use that to build your own product, however it will take considerable amount of effort.